# Updating laravel to laravel 5.5 from laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I'm trying update a laravel from 5.4 version to 5.5. I have done everything with instruction from laravel guide: 
https://laravel.com/docs/master/upgrade

When I'm trying use command:

```
composer update
```

the result is:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package laravel/framework 5.5.* is satisfiable by laravel/framework[5.5.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
```

Below I show **composer.json** file:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.6.4",
        "doctrine/dbal": "^2.5",
        "intervention/image": "^2.3",
        "laravel/framework": "5.5.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
        "laravelcollective/html": "^5.4.0",
        "unisharp/laravel-filemanager": "^1.7"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~6.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "artSite\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    }
}
```

I would be greateful for help. Best regards

Comment: Possibly because it's not actually out yet as far as I know? It gets released at Laracon EU

Comment: Yeah, Laravel 5.5 isn't out yet.

Comment: It looks in the final stage as they added 5.5 docs on the site, so I guess we can update to dev now, as there will be ver less changes in final release from now.

Comment: Haha this docs update is very confusing. It mention that it's a dev version nowhere(!). P.S. Didn't even know Laracon EU was a thing!

Comment: It is a released and a stable version. Reinstall the composer to fix your problem.

Answer (score 11):

as stated in the error message Laravel 5.5 is still in dev, meaning there's no stable release and by default Composer limits you to downloading only stable numbered releases to avoid you downloading any packages that are in active development and may contain breaking changes.

You can circumvent this by adding the following two lines to your *composer.json* file

```
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": true,
```

This way it **prefers** stable releases wherever it can find them but it will allow you to download `dev` packages if nothing else is available.

Comment: Thank you for the (temporary) solution. It seems that currently it will pull `master` branch with this config? I've checked and there seem to be commits to the `master` branch daily, so I guess won't risk it myself at the moment. Thanks nonetheless @JonnySerra !

Answer (score 0):

I think you should update the PHP version as well. If you check the official [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5), it says the minimum PHP requirement 7.0.0.